# How to avoid old value flashed after view updated in Angular?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, web, frontend, angularjs-components

In my angular app, there is an main app component which have a event listener:

```
...
$scope.$on('page::change', function(e, value) {
  self.navList = value;
});
...
```

And a navigation component inside app component, it has only one varible which bind to navList inside app component:

```
app.component('navBar', {
  bindings: {
    list: '<',
  },
  templateUrl: 'templates/e/navBar.html',
  ...
});
```

Inside navBar.html, I use ng-repeat to display the data of 'list':

```
<nav>
    <a ng-repeat="(key,value) in Nav.list" ng-href="{{ value }}" ng-bind="key"></a>
</nav>
```

Whenever I change the value of navList inside the app, or I emit an event of 'page::change', the view of data will flash in webpage like:

Original:

```
OldValue
```

And then flash:

```
NewValue OldValue
```

Then finally:

```
NewValue
```

How should I fix this? The version of anuglar is 1.5.8

Comment: Do you wan't to keep both(old and new) values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem sometimes and my solution was to put an element around to avoid to many bindings to one element:

```
<nav>
    <span ng-repeat="(key,value) in Nav.list">
       <a ng-href="{{value}}">{{key}}</a>
    </span>
</nav>
```

I don't know whether this could help you in your situation, but i might be a try.

Answer (score 1):

You could try this:

```
$scope.$watch('modelName' ,  function ( newValue, oldValue )  { 
  // access new and old value here
  console.log("Your former modelName was "+oldValue+", your current modelName value "+newValue+".");
});
```

Comment: Yep, I try this one to test it. It updates in the right way. But only the view changes directly. It supposed to change like from 'oldValue' -> 'newValue', in my view it changes like 'oldValue' -> 'newValue oldValue' -> 'newValue'. The final result is correct but the view flashed.

Comment: Sorry, I mean doesn't change directly.

Comment: Then I would suggest that while binding the values clear the previous value : example: $scope.myName= " ";

Comment: Do you mean assign an empty value to navList? Where should I put the code? If I change it continuously, it still doesn't work

Comment: You can write any where inside your controller